# verify if input on password-input-type-box is correct show button that will link to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, verify

I need a (custom css button. I already have the style but i just need some codes) button that is hidden at first, and if the input in the password box is correct then pressing 'submit' would create another button above/below it that says 'proceed'. Or if not, then something that if input value is correct, then the submit button would link to another website, if not, then it would alert that it's the wrong password.

Please I really need help with this.

If possible, and if most possible, not jQuery or pHp codes

HTML, css, javascript would be very helpful

Thanks in advance!

Oh, by the way, the command 'window.location.href' thingy doesn't work. I tried it and idk why. I also tried the other three like window.location, location.href and etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: If you dont want to have serious security issues, you need to have some php background script, you could send the password and username via ajax to and get a correct or incorrect in return

Comment: oh sorry, im still a student and i just wanted a plain notepad html website that would confirm if the input is correct then it would go to the main site xD... hehe. I'm new around here. but thanks for the help anyways !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily done by PHP code...

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password']))
{
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password))
{
if($password==$blahblah)    //$blahblah is your correct password 
   header("LOCATION: home.php");      //$password is your typed one
else                             //home.php is your link after correct login
header("LOCATION: tryagain.php"); //tryagain is link for wrong password
}
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="xyz.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

while submitting form you should also use sql injection..u can learn about this on google...